# Google Analytics in HTML5 APK

Tags: android, html, google-analytics, apk

Android supports HTML5 based apps. We can even make an interface script between Java and JavaScript. Can I put a Google Analytics tracker script in a HTML5 based Android app?

Comment: Why not just integrate with [Google Analytic for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) ?

Comment: Maybe, I will add this as an answer for other people to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, alternatively, you can integrate the native [Google Analytic for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) SDK into your app.